# I need help making this random quiz generator. i cant get the looping or the questioning part working correctly

Tags: python

so i need help with the looping and the inputting the answer to the question  along side with making the question generate differently each time

```
answered = 0
correct = 0
import random

ops = ['+', '-', '*',]
num1 = random.randint(0,10)
num2 = random.randint(0,10)
operation = random.choice(ops)

print(num1)
print(operation)
print(num2)

maths = eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2))

while answered <= 10:
    print("what is" ,num1, operation, num2,)
    input`enter code here`
   if input == maths:
        answered = answered + 1
        correct = correct + 1
        print("correct")
    elif input != maths:
        answered = answered + 1
        print("incorrect")
```

Comment: You need to put the num1 = and num2 = lines at the start of the while loop.  Also, you need to lookup how input works (its a function and it returns a value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the random choices into a function and call it at the end of each `if-statement` like so:

```
import random

answered = 0
correct = 0

ops = ['+', '-', '*',]
num1 = random.randint(0,10)
num2 = random.randint(0,10)
operation = random.choice(ops)

maths = eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2))

combined = [num1, operation, num2]

def shuffle():
    global ops, num1, num2, operation, maths, combined
    ops = ['+', '-', '*',]
    num1 = random.randint(0,10)
    num2 = random.randint(0,10)
    operation = random.choice(ops)

    maths = eval(str(num1) + operation + str(num2))

    combined = [num1, operation, num2]


while answered <= 10:
    ans = int(input("what is {}".format(combined)))
    if ans == maths:
        answered += 1
        correct += 1
        print("Correct")
        print("Answered: ", answered, "Correct: ", correct)
        shuffle()
    elif ans != maths:
        answered = answered + 1
        print("Incorrect")
        shuffle()
```

I've put `num1`, `num2`, and `operation` into a list so you can use `int(input))` in one line but you can change that if you please.

```
print("What is " ,num1, operation, num2)
ans = int(input())
```

Then you can remove `combined` completely.

Comment: is there anyway that i can remove the square brackets, commas and the inverted commas? as it outputs [4, '-', 4]

Comment: By not using the `combined`, check the lower part of my answer below the block of code.

Answer (score -3):

I think it should be:

```
while answered <= 10:
    print("what is" ,num1, operation, num2,)
    input`enter code here`
    if input == maths: {
        answered = answered + 1
        correct = correct + 1
        print("correct")
        }
    elif input != maths: {
        answered = answered + 1
        print("incorrect")
        }
```

Comment: You haven't changed a thing except add curly brackets and the above code will still throw syntax errors